# Why can't I enable or disable my GlassFish application through the REST API?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

When I submit a REST request, EG: (included auth is for admin/adminadmin)

```
curl -ik -X POST -H "Accept: application/json"
  -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg=="
  https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/MyApp/enable
```

GlassFish just rejects the request:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 10:33:06 GMT
Connection: close
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've used the GET method to check the command parameters and they're all optional.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/general-administration.htm

> REST requests that add, update, or delete objects must specify the X-Requested-By header with the value "GlassFish REST HTML interface".

So EG:

```
curl -ik -X POST -H "Accept: application/json"
  -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg=="
  -H "X-Requested-By: GlassFish REST HTML interface"
  https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/MyApp/enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697788/10966651), ajusted for those who try to do it with the successor of Glassfish - the Payara Server:

***Enable App***

```
curl -ik -X POST \
  -H 'accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'x-requested-by: GlassFish REST HTML interface' \
  --data target=server \
  --url https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/awesomeApp/enable
```

***Disable App***

```
curl -ik -X POST \
  -H 'accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'x-requested-by: GlassFish REST HTML interface' \
  --data target=server \
  --url https://localhost:4848/management/domain/applications/application/awesomeApp/disable
```